# How to prove this algebra question?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x=y^2+z^2$,  $y=x^2+z^2,$ and $z=x^2+y^2$ then show that $$\frac{x}{x+1}+\frac{y}{y+1}+\frac{z}{z+1}=1$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

$x-y=y^2-x^2=(y-x)(y+x)$. So either $x=y$ or $x+y+1=0$. Do the same with other pairs.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=x(x+1)\implies\dfrac x{x+1}=?$$